# I want to throw a star in the direction of drag done by user

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I want to develop a game in which the user will drag towards a target and as soon as he drags, a star will be thrown at the target. But I am getting problems in the very early stages of this development. I am not able move the star in angular direction. I did the following code, but the star goes as user drags. I don't want like that. I want it as follows: if the user drags in particular direction then the star will be thrown in that direction; straightly not in a curvy manner.

here's what I tried :

```
       private void OnUpdate(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
    {
        TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.FreeDrag | GestureType.DragComplete ;

        if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
        }

            switch(gesture.GestureType)
                {
                    case GestureType.FreeDrag:

                        position = gesture.Position * 1.2f;

                       break;

                }

    }
```

Comment: Use a vector2 start point and get when the user clicks the button. Then wait till user unblocked button and use a vector2 to get end position. Then get angle between points and send star in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
Vector2 startSwipePos; // When the user starts swiping
Vector2 endSwipePos; // When the user ends swiping, define those two
Vector2 difference = endSwipePos - startSwipePos;
difference.Normalize(); // Get only the direction, you don't have to do this,
                        // you can also make the speed less instead.
Vector2 velocity = difference * (SPEED HERE IN FLOAT);
pos += velocity;
```

See also this: http://xnafan.net/2012/12/pointing-and-moving-towards-a-target-in-xna-2d/